# bcp to extract data from SQL query to local machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am using below code

```
bcp "SELECT COL1 FROM DBO.V_VIEW_1" queryout d:\VIEW_PART1.csv -S AB6Y7YYY,1433 -c -t",", -T
```

AB6Y7YYY : I got this with below code in SSMS

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

I am able to see VIEW_PART1.csv in d drive but it is empty and error in command line is as below

```
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 10061
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `AB6Y7YYY` instance actually listening on port 1433? When connecting with SSMS what are you entering into the `Server name` input? When looking at the instance's Server Protocol configuration via the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager does it have the TCP/IP Protocol enabled?

Comment: Yes, while connecting to SSMS, I enter that same @@SERVERNAEM as input. Client Protocols : TCP/IP is enabled. Can I use some other code here  to get the data without 1433 port or using Windows authentication ?

Comment: I didn't say _Client Protocols_. Did you check the __Server Protocols__?